# jq curl vs local file: jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index string with string "joke"

Tags: jq

Why is this not working:

```
curl -s http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3 | jq '.[] | .joke'
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index string with string "joke"
```

When this is:

```
jq '.[] | .joke' jokes.json                                   
"Chuck Norris hosting is 101% uptime guaranteed."
"The crossing lights in Chuck Norris's home town say &quot;Die slowly&quot; and &quot;die quickly&quot;. They each have a picture of Chuck Norris punching or kicking a pedestrian."
"When in a bar, you can order a drink called a &quot;Chuck Norris&quot;. It is also known as a &quot;Bloody Mary&quot;, if your name happens to be Mary."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl -s http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3 | jq '.value[].joke'
```

works fine here.

Comment: You added ".value" ?

Comment: Also I am testing multiple filters

Comment: @ChrisG. yeah, the json that api returns has jokes under key `value`

Comment: ahh man, yes totally :-) I am trying out jq and already did a download with | jq '.[]' without thinking. Thanks

Comment: But for multiple filters, this does not work:curl -s http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3 | jq '.value[] | .joke'